# Indexes for a multi-column join: multi-column index or multiple indexes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say my join looks like this:

```
ON A.col1 = B.col1 and A.col2= B.col2
```

Say I want to create indexes on both tables. I think it is better to create two indexes on each table, i.e for table A:

```
create index NC1 on A(col1);
create index NC2 on A(col2);
```

And so on for table B.

But one could also use:

```
create index NC on A(col1,col2);
create index NC on B(col1,col2);
```

Which is better?

Comment: There are no absolutes with regard to performance. To know which is better FOR YOU 
 means you should try both and evaluate "performance". Keep in mind that nothing is free. Indexes need  to be maintained. Every index has a cost and (hopefully) a benefit. You will likely need indexes on both tables - you seem to have overlooked that aspect.

Comment: I would expect the composite index to be more optimal but, as @SMor suggested, there are other trade-offs and considerations.